# Equivalent of bokeh serve --show myapp in full python

Tags: python, eclipse, bokeh

I worked a lot with Bokeh app. And I need both to debug them step by step and to deliver them. (If relevant, I am used to work in eclipse IDE and Python debug mode provided by PyDev is convenient to me.)

But when I deliver my app, I launch it through `bokeh serve --show myapp`.

This does not allow any debug mode from eclipe as launched in command line.
When I want to debug my app, I launched separately `bokeh serve` command in a terminal, and on eclipse side, I run my app which ends with the following piece of code, dedicated to debug mode (switched on based on a arg):

```
session = push_session(curdoc())
session.show() # open the document in a browser
session.loop_until_closed() # run forever
```

Is that possible to have a common way to launch a bokeh app, either for usage or debugging ? In other words, can I rely fully on python code to deliver my bokeh app, without relying on extra command lines ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For bokeh v0.12.6 it could be:

```
import random
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource

def make_document(doc):
    source = ColumnDataSource({'x': [], 'y': [], 'color': []})

    def update():
        source.stream({'x': [random.random()], 'y': [random.random()], 'color': [random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])]})

    doc.add_periodic_callback(update, 100)

    fig = figure(title = 'Streaming Circle Plot!', sizing_mode = 'scale_both')
    fig.circle(source = source, x = 'x', y = 'y', color = 'color', size = 10)

    doc.add_root(fig)

io_loop = IOLoop.current()
server = Server({'/myapp': Application(FunctionHandler(make_document))}, port = 5001, io_loop = io_loop)
server.start()
server.show('/myapp')
io_loop.start()
```